# Nuxt 'npm run dev' suddenly keeps failing ('Error: cannot find module fs-extra') since using Firebase database in Vuex store

Tags: typescript, firebase-realtime-database, nuxt.js, vuex

**Context**: Nuxt App with TypeScript. Recently installed and started using Firebase Realtime Database. I am using Nuxt/Firebase Module, but not the Vuexfire Module.

**Problem**: Server suddenly won't start. `npm run dev` throws error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:361
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/macbookpro2021/Documents/dev/BLVU/node_modules/@nuxt/utils/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:353:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:566:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/macbookpro2021/Documents/dev/BLVU/node_modules/@nuxt/utils/dist/utils.js:15:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: '/Users/macbookpro2021/Documents/dev/BLVU/node_modules/@nuxt/utils/node_modules/fs-extra/package.json',
  requestPath: 'fs-extra'
}
```

Before the error started appearing I did not make any changes to `nuxt.config.js`. However, I recently started accessing a realtime Firebase database from my Vuex store.  It worked fine. Until I tried to restart my server.

**Additional information**:
**Vuex store**

```
export const state = () => ({
  testProjects: 'Test Projects',
  testProgram: 'Test Program',
  testColumns: 'Test Columns',
  testMembers: 'Test Members'
})

export const getters = {}

// Actions are async
export const actions = {
  async getProjects( context ) {
    this.$fire.database.ref('projects').on('value', snapshot => context.commit('setProjects', snapshot.val() ))
  },
  async getProgram( context ) {
    this.$fire.database.ref('program').on('value', snapshot => context.commit('setProgram', snapshot.val() ))
  },
  async getColumns( context ) {
    this.$fire.database.ref('columns').on('value', snapshot => context.commit('setColumns', snapshot.val() ))
  },
  async getMembers( context ) {
    this.$fire.database.ref('members').on('value', snapshot => context.commit('setMembers', snapshot.val() ))
  }
}

// Mutations change states
export const mutations = {
  setProjects ( state, projects ) {
    state.test = projects
  },
  setProgram ( state, program ) {
    state.test = program
  },
  setColumns ( state, columns ) {
    state.test = columns
  },
  setMembers ( state, members ) {
    state.test = members
  }
}
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
export default {
  ssr: false,

  head: {
    title: 'MY_TITLE',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  css: [
    '@/assets/css/global.css'
  ],

  plugins: [
  ],

  components: true,

  buildModules: [
    '@nuxt/typescript-build'
  ],

  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/firebase'
  ],

  axios: {},

  firebase: {
    config: {
      apiKey: '<MY_INFO>',
      authDomain: '<MY_INFO>',
      databaseURL: '<MY_INFO>',
      projectId: '<MY_INFO>',
      storageBucket: '<MY_INFO>',
      messagingSenderId: '<MY_INFO>',
      appId: '<MY_INFO>',
      measurementId: '<MY_INFO>'
    },
    services: {
      auth: false,
      database: true
    }
  },

  build: {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the error.

**Solution**: Inside my packages.json, I changed `"@nuxtjs/firebase": "~8.1.1"` to `"@nuxtjs/firebase": "^8.1.1"` by running `npm install @nuxtjs/firebase@^8.1.1 --force`.

I had to use `--force` flag, because of an `upstream dependency conflict` between my `firebase` and `@nuxtjs/firebase` module.

Running `npm install @nuxtjs/firebase@~8.1.1 --force` solved the `upstream dependency conflict` for me some time ago, but now apparently caused problems.